# How many characters in varchar(max)?

Tags: sql-server-2008, size, varchar

How many characters can a SQL Server 2008 database field contain when the data type is VARCHAR(MAX)?

Comment: check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28980502/sql-varcharmax-vs-varcharfix

Answer (score 70, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx

> varchar [ ( n | max ) ]
>   Variable-length, non-Unicode character
>   data. n can be a value from 1 through
>   8,000. max indicates that the maximum
>   storage size is 2^31-1 bytes. The
>   storage size is the actual length of
>   data entered + 2 bytes. The data
>   entered can be 0 characters in length.
>   The ISO synonyms for varchar are char
>   varying or character varying.

1 character = 1 byte.  And don't forget 2 bytes for the termination.  So, 2^31-3 characters.

Comment: Technically, 1 character = 1 byte only for certain character encodings.

Comment: Ah true.  DBCS strings, e.g., would give you less.  So, watch out for that.

Comment: @Dav, yeah that was one of my considerations too.  However due to the number of bytes available, this will meet my needs for this scenario.

Comment: That's about half way to .2 in `2.1 x 10^9` for those of us who aren't calculators.

Comment: Not to be that guy, but... 2^31 bytes (2 gigs)... if there's enough internal memory to handle it... all the times it's being used and filled with that much data... i.e. there's also a memory concern...

Answer (score 74):

For future readers who need this answer quickly:

> 2^31-1 = 2 147 483 647 characters, or roughly 2.147 billion

Answer (score 8):

See the [MSDN reference table for maximum numbers/sizes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx).

> Bytes per varchar(max),
>   varbinary(max), xml, text, or image
>   column: 2^31-1

There's a two-byte overhead for the column, so the actual data is 2^31-3 max bytes in length. Assuming you're using a single-byte character encoding, that's 2^31-3 characters total. (If you're using a character encoding that uses more than one byte per character, divide by the total number of bytes per character. If you're using a variable-length character encoding, all bets are off.)

Answer (score 2):

There are a few gotchas worth mentioning - you may need to force the use of varchar(max)

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18483/varcharmax-field-cutting-off-data-after-8000-characters

and print only handles 8000 chars

[How to print VARCHAR(MAX) using Print Statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850477/how-to-print-varcharmax-using-print-statement/10206672)