# Check if concatenating to a varchar(max) will go beyond max allowable characters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, varchar

I am trying to concatenate a list of IDs into a varchar(max) to pass into an openquery for a bulk update of data.

My question is, is there an easy way to see if a string is beyond the length a varchar(max) can handle aside from comparing it to the number?

I have seen this: [How many characters in varchar(max)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761124/how-many-characters-in-varcharmax)
which specifies the exact length of a varchar(max), but I was hoping for a simpler method than comparing length to a static numeric value.

Please let me know if any more information is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The max length of varchar(max) is 2GB however **openquery only takes 8K** according to [Books On Line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188427.aspx)

OPENQUERY (linked_server ,'query')
Arguments
linked_server
Is an identifier representing the name of the linked server.

'query'
Is the query string executed in the linked server. **The maximum length of the string is 8 KB.**

Comment: I hadn't even thought of the max length of the openquery.
Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the sql server you can use `print(@sql)` at the end, and it will indicate where you have reached the maximum amount of characters. I had reached the maximum amount and to delete some extra space where there was no special characters, and it worked.