# SQL nvarchar concatenation truncates dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server

I am building a dynamic SQL command using the following SQL instructions

```
DECLARE @fechaIni as Date
DECLARE @fechaFin as Date

DECLARE @fecha as Date
DECLARE @numDoc as NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @nombre as NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @curTripulantes as CURSOR
DECLARE @sql as NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @col as NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @primeraFila as bit

--parametros del SP
SET @fechaIni = '2016-01-01'
SET @fechaFin = '2016-01-05'
--


SET @sql = N'' 
SET @primeraFila = 1 

SET @curTripulantes = CURSOR FOR
SELECT TRI.NumeroDocumento, TRI.Nombre
FROM   [adm].[Tripulantes] as TRI
ORDER BY TRI.Nombre

OPEN @curTripulantes
FETCH NEXT
FROM @curTripulantes INTO @numDoc,@nombre
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    --PRINT @numDoc + '-' +  @nombre
    IF @primeraFila = 1
        SET @sql = @sql + N'SELECT ''' + @numDoc + N''' as NumeroDocumento,''' + @nombre + N''' as Tripulante'   
    ELSE
        SET @sql = @sql + N'SELECT ''' + @numDoc + N''' ,''' + @nombre + N''''   

    SET @fecha = @fechaIni

    WHILE @fecha <= @fechaFin
    BEGIN
        SET @col = convert(nvarchar(max),@fecha)

        IF @primeraFila = 1 
            SET @sql = @sql + N',[adm].[FunTKA] (''' + @numDoc + N''',''' +  @col + ''') as ''' + @col + N''''
        ELSE
            SET @sql = @sql + N',[adm].[FunTKA] (''' + @numDoc + N''',''' +  @col + ''')'  
        --PRINT @fecha
        SET @fecha = dateadd(day,1,@fecha) 
    END

    SET @primeraFila = 0 
    SET @sql = @sql + N' UNION ' 


    FETCH NEXT
    FROM @curTripulantes INTO @numDoc,@nombre
END

CLOSE @curTripulantes
DEALLOCATE @curTripulantes

--remover el ultimo ' UNION ' 
set @sql = left(@sql, len(@sql) - 7)


PRINT @sql

PRINT (len(@sql))
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

The lentgh of @sql is 17178 and 
contains this

```
SELECT '72205126' as NumeroDocumento,'ACOSTA PAGUANA JORGE LUIS' as Tripulante,[adm].[FunTKA] ('72205126','2016-01-01') as '2016-01-01',[adm].[FunTKA] ('72205126','2016-01-02') as '2016-01-02',[adm].[FunTKA] ('72205126','2016-01-03') as '2016-01-03',[adm].[FunTKA] ('72205126','2016-01-04') as '2016-01-04',[adm].[FunTKA] ('72205126','2016-01-05') as '2016-01-05' UNION SELECT '1048210196' ,'ALTAMAR QUIROZ KEVIS DE JESUS',[adm].[FunTKA] ('1048210196','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1048210196','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1048210196','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1048210196','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1048210196','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '85160032' ,'AMARIS GOMEZ PROSPERO',[adm].[FunTKA] ('85160032','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('85160032','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('85160032','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('85160032','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('85160032','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '3779564' ,'ANGULO REDONDO OSCAR',[adm].[FunTKA] ('3779564','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('3779564','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('3779564','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('3779564','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('3779564','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '8735712' ,'ARAGON QUIÑONES LUILLYS ALCIDES',[adm].[FunTKA] ('8735712','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8735712','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8735712','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8735712','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8735712','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '73097668' ,'ARANGO BENAVIDES LUIS JAVIER',[adm].[FunTKA] ('73097668','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('73097668','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('73097668','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('73097668','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('73097668','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '8694204' ,'ATENCIA FERIO CARLOS ALFREDO',[adm].[FunTKA] ('8694204','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8694204','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8694204','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8694204','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8694204','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '7457325' ,'BETTER FLOREZ ROBERTO ANTONIO',[adm].[FunTKA] ('7457325','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('7457325','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('7457325','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('7457325','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('7457325','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '84453969' ,'CAMARGO ESTRADA CHARLY DE JESUS',[adm].[FunTKA] ('84453969','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('84453969','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('84453969','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('84453969','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('84453969','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '8757328' ,'CARDENAS DAJER JULIO CESAR',[adm].[FunTKA] ('8757328','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8757328','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8757328','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8757328','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8757328','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '19266623' ,'CARDENAS SANTOS JUAN DE DIOS',[adm].[FunTKA] ('19266623','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('19266623','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('19266623','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('19266623','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('19266623','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '1085226693' ,'CARREÑO MERCADO ELIECER DE JESUS',[adm].[FunTKA] ('1085226693','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1085226693','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1085226693','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1085226693','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1085226693','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '85454314' ,'CASTRILLO VALDEBLANQUEZ EZEQUIEL',[adm].[FunTKA] ('85454314','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('85454314','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('85454314','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('85454314','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('85454314','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '8723807' ,'CUADRADO GALVIS WALFRAN',[adm].[FunTKA] ('8723807','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8723807','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8723807','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8723807','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8723807','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '8641883' ,'CUADRO AREYANO WILMAR',[adm].[FunTKA] ('8641883','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8641883','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8641883','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8641883','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8641883','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT
```

As you can see it ends in "UNION SELECT" like if the cursor or while statement was being interrupted

I have read that nvarchar(max) has a limit for 2GB and that I need to use the N' prefix to make sure that everything is treated as nvarchar.As you can see the concatenation is using that N' prefix

Is not only a PRINT problem I am getting error (when the exec tries to run the dinamically created query @sql)

```
'Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '2016-01-05'.'
```

After using Alex advice to show the whole SQL using 'SELECT CONVERT(xml, @sql)' here is the complete SQL (that is being truncated)

SELECT '72205126' as NumeroDocumento,'ACOSTA PAGUANA JORGE LUIS' as Tripulante,[adm].[FunTKA] ('72205126','2016-01-01') as '2016-01-01',[adm].[FunTKA] ('72205126','2016-01-02') as '2016-01-02',[adm].[FunTKA] ('72205126','2016-01-03') as '2016-01-03',[adm].[FunTKA] ('72205126','2016-01-04') as '2016-01-04',[adm].[FunTKA] ('72205126','2016-01-05') as '2016-01-05' UNION SELECT '1048210196' ,'ALTAMAR QUIROZ KEVIS DE JESUS',[adm].[FunTKA] ('1048210196','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1048210196','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1048210196','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1048210196','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1048210196','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '85160032' ,'AMARIS GOMEZ PROSPERO',[adm].[FunTKA] ('85160032','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('85160032','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('85160032','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('85160032','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('85160032','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '3779564' ,'ANGULO REDONDO OSCAR',[adm].[FunTKA] ('3779564','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('3779564','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('3779564','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('3779564','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('3779564','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '8735712' ,'ARAGON QUIÑONES LUILLYS ALCIDES',[adm].[FunTKA] ('8735712','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8735712','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8735712','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8735712','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8735712','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '73097668' ,'ARANGO BENAVIDES LUIS JAVIER',[adm].[FunTKA] ('73097668','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('73097668','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('73097668','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('73097668','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('73097668','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '8694204' ,'ATENCIA FERIO CARLOS ALFREDO',[adm].[FunTKA] ('8694204','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8694204','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8694204','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8694204','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8694204','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '7457325' ,'BETTER FLOREZ ROBERTO ANTONIO',[adm].[FunTKA] ('7457325','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('7457325','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('7457325','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('7457325','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('7457325','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '84453969' ,'CAMARGO ESTRADA CHARLY DE JESUS',[adm].[FunTKA] ('84453969','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('84453969','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('84453969','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('84453969','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('84453969','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '8757328' ,'CARDENAS DAJER JULIO CESAR',[adm].[FunTKA] ('8757328','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8757328','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8757328','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8757328','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8757328','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '19266623' ,'CARDENAS SANTOS JUAN DE DIOS',[adm].[FunTKA] ('19266623','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('19266623','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('19266623','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('19266623','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('19266623','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '1085226693' ,'CARREÑO MERCADO ELIECER DE JESUS',[adm].[FunTKA] ('1085226693','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1085226693','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1085226693','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1085226693','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1085226693','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '85454314' ,'CASTRILLO VALDEBLANQUEZ EZEQUIEL',[adm].[FunTKA] ('85454314','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('85454314','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('85454314','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('85454314','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('85454314','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '8723807' ,'CUADRADO GALVIS WALFRAN',[adm].[FunTKA] ('8723807','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8723807','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8723807','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8723807','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8723807','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '8641883' ,'CUADRO AREYANO WILMAR',[adm].[FunTKA] ('8641883','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8641883','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8641883','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8641883','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8641883','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '19520065' ,'DE ARCO MARTINEZ LUIS ENRIQUE',[adm].[FunTKA] ('19520065','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('19520065','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('19520065','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('19520065','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('19520065','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '73105721' ,'DEL RIO CORINA ANGEL ARTURO',[adm].[FunTKA] ('73105721','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('73105721','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('73105721','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('73105721','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('73105721','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '7478627' ,'DIAZ SABALZA JUAN DE DIOS',[adm].[FunTKA] ('7478627','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('7478627','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('7478627','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('7478627','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('7478627','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '72143225' ,'GONZALEZ NATERA JULIO ENRIQUE',[adm].[FunTKA] ('72143225','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72143225','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72143225','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72143225','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72143225','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '91446425' ,'GUTIERREZ OSPNA BERTULFO ALFONSO',[adm].[FunTKA] ('91446425','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('91446425','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('91446425','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('91446425','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('91446425','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '73145657' ,'HOY FRANCO LUIS ALBERTO ',[adm].[FunTKA] ('73145657','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('73145657','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('73145657','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('73145657','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('73145657','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '8749179' ,'JIMENEZ GIL JOSE CELESTINO',[adm].[FunTKA] ('8749179','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8749179','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8749179','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8749179','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8749179','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '8567326' ,'JIMENEZ REYES DEYVIS ENRIQUE',[adm].[FunTKA] ('8567326','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8567326','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8567326','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8567326','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8567326','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '72148884' ,'LEAL MARQUEZ JUAN JESUS',[adm].[FunTKA] ('72148884','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72148884','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72148884','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72148884','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72148884','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '9140802' ,'LOPEZ MARTINEZ MANUEL DE JESUS',[adm].[FunTKA] ('9140802','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('9140802','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('9140802','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('9140802','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('9140802','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '71652977' ,'MARIN VASQUEZ JORGE EVELIO',[adm].[FunTKA] ('71652977','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('71652977','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('71652977','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('71652977','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('71652977','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '72138435' ,'MARTINEZ CORRADO FERNANDO ENRIQUE',[adm].[FunTKA] ('72138435','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72138435','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72138435','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72138435','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72138435','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '1052052101' ,'MARTINEZ ROJAS JORGE LUIS',[adm].[FunTKA] ('1052052101','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1052052101','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1052052101','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1052052101','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1052052101','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '1036133230' ,'MEDINA CASTRO YERSON ANDRES',[adm].[FunTKA] ('1036133230','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1036133230','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1036133230','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1036133230','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1036133230','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '3811186' ,'MEJIA VILLAREAL RICARDO ',[adm].[FunTKA] ('3811186','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('3811186','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('3811186','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('3811186','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('3811186','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '8704466' ,'MERCADO POLO JESUS MARIA',[adm].[FunTKA] ('8704466','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8704466','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8704466','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8704466','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8704466','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '8703951' ,'MERCADO ZABALETA PROSPERO',[adm].[FunTKA] ('8703951','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8703951','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8703951','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8703951','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8703951','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '5117448' ,'MIRANDA MERCADO LUIS ALFREDO',[adm].[FunTKA] ('5117448','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('5117448','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('5117448','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('5117448','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('5117448','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '3982891' ,'MORON PAYARES JAIME',[adm].[FunTKA] ('3982891','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('3982891','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('3982891','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('3982891','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('3982891','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '1129536224' ,'OROZCO BARRIOS JANER ANTONIO',[adm].[FunTKA] ('1129536224','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1129536224','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1129536224','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1129536224','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1129536224','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '12685576' ,'OROZCO MARRIAGA JOSE ANTONIO',[adm].[FunTKA] ('12685576','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('12685576','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('12685576','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('12685576','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('12685576','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '72346476' ,'ORTEGA MIRANDA LUIS ALFREDO',[adm].[FunTKA] ('72346476','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72346476','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72346476','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72346476','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72346476','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '8761271' ,'PACHECO CUETO ANGEL CUSTODIO',[adm].[FunTKA] ('8761271','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8761271','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8761271','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8761271','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8761271','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '85152394' ,'PALOMINO OSPINO ALAN JOSE',[adm].[FunTKA] ('85152394','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('85152394','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('85152394','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('85152394','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('85152394','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '72125634' ,'PEREZ MUÑOZ REINALDO ANTONIO',[adm].[FunTKA] ('72125634','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72125634','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72125634','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72125634','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72125634','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '12559374' ,'PINTO ACOSTA RAMIRO RAFAEL',[adm].[FunTKA] ('12559374','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('12559374','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('12559374','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('12559374','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('12559374','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '19860139' ,'QUESADA CONTRERAS DOMINGO',[adm].[FunTKA] ('19860139','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('19860139','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('19860139','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('19860139','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('19860139','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '9139359' ,'REALES ESPAÑA JOSE ANTONIO ',[adm].[FunTKA] ('9139359','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('9139359','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('9139359','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('9139359','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('9139359','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '72263838' ,'REDONDO MARTINZ YAIR ERNESTO',[adm].[FunTKA] ('72263838','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72263838','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72263838','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72263838','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72263838','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '14474121' ,'RENDON RAMOS JOSE ABEL',[adm].[FunTKA] ('14474121','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('14474121','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('14474121','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('14474121','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('14474121','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '1052084778' ,'RIVAS GONZALEZ JESUS ALBERTO',[adm].[FunTKA] ('1052084778','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1052084778','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1052084778','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1052084778','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1052084778','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '3770835' ,'RUIZ FONTALVO FREDY ALBERTO',[adm].[FunTKA] ('3770835','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('3770835','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('3770835','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('3770835','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('3770835','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '3770347' ,'RUIZ FONTALVO REMIGIO ANTONIO',[adm].[FunTKA] ('3770347','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('3770347','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('3770347','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('3770347','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('3770347','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '1052965836' ,'RUIZ MARTINEZ IGNACIO JOSE',[adm].[FunTKA] ('1052965836','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1052965836','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1052965836','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1052965836','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('1052965836','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '71180155' ,'RUIZ PULGARIN ELKIN DE JESUS',[adm].[FunTKA] ('71180155','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('71180155','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('71180155','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('71180155','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('71180155','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '12552673' ,'SALAS DE LA HOZ JOSMAN FIDEL',[adm].[FunTKA] ('12552673','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('12552673','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('12552673','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('12552673','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('12552673','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '3811854' ,'SALAS HERRERA EDWIN',[adm].[FunTKA] ('3811854','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('3811854','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('3811854','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('3811854','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('3811854','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '8834272' ,'SALAS HIDALGO REICARDO',[adm].[FunTKA] ('8834272','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8834272','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8834272','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8834272','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8834272','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '71941295' ,'SANABRIA HERNANDEZ LUIS ADOLFO',[adm].[FunTKA] ('71941295','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('71941295','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('71941295','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('71941295','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('71941295','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '94280974' ,'SANCHEZ CARDONA RUBIEL ALEXANDER',[adm].[FunTKA] ('94280974','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('94280974','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('94280974','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('94280974','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('94280974','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '8760184' ,'SANCHEZ JAIRO',[adm].[FunTKA] ('8760184','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8760184','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8760184','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8760184','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('8760184','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '15241962' ,'SARAVIA MELENDEZ VICTOS ',[adm].[FunTKA] ('15241962','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('15241962','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('15241962','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('15241962','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('15241962','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '72097857' ,'SUAREZ VILORIA DONALDO CESAR',[adm].[FunTKA] ('72097857','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72097857','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72097857','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72097857','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72097857','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '73569172' ,'TABORDA MELENDEZ ALFONSO IDELMAR',[adm].[FunTKA] ('73569172','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('73569172','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('73569172','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('73569172','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('73569172','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '73570761' ,'TORRES ESPINOSA JOSE GREGORIO',[adm].[FunTKA] ('73570761','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('73570761','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('73570761','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('73570761','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('73570761','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '72308932' ,'VALDELAMAR RODELO RAFAEL GREGORIO',[adm].[FunTKA] ('72308932','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72308932','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72308932','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72308932','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('72308932','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '7140355' ,'VARGAS PACHECO JHON JAIRO',[adm].[FunTKA] ('7140355','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('7140355','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('7140355','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('7140355','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('7140355','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '19515677' ,'VENERA MEJIA DAMIAN ENRIQUE',[adm].[FunTKA] ('19515677','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('19515677','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('19515677','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('19515677','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('19515677','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '15670666' ,'VIZCAINO HERNANDEZ ALFONSO ALCIDEZ',[adm].[FunTKA] ('15670666','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('15670666','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('15670666','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('15670666','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('15670666','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '13885246' ,'YEPES YOVIRA FAVIO',[adm].[FunTKA] ('13885246','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('13885246','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('13885246','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('13885246','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('13885246','2016-01-05') UNION SELECT '7938177' ,'ZAMBRANO CAICEDO JORGE ARMANDO',[adm].[FunTKA] ('7938177','2016-01-01'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('7938177','2016-01-02'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('7938177','2016-01-03'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('7938177','2016-01-04'),[adm].[FunTKA] ('7938177','2016-01-05'

What can be causing this behaviour ? How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PRINT command has a limit of 8000 characters (see [How to print VARCHAR(MAX) using Print Statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850477/how-to-print-varcharmax-using-print-statement)) 
You can either use the workaround provided in the above link or output your string as follows:

```
SELECT CONVERT( @sql AS XML )
```

The will return your text as a result set, clicking on the link in the result set will open a new window with the full query.

Note: In order for the above to work make sure that in SSMS:
"XML Data" option is set to a reasonably large size. or "Unlimited"
You can find this option by going Tools->Options, then, in the tree on the left, select "Query Results"->"SQL Server"->"Results To Grid".

Updates:
RE: Is not only a PRINT problem I am getting error
Once you are able to get the whole string PRINTed, paste it into SSMS query window.
Scroll to the end to see if the end of the query is valid e.g. no trailing UNION SELECT all brackets and text delimeters are closed etc.
Run it directly from SSMS. If getting the error then you have to search for the offending string ("2016-01-05") and check each instance manually.

Comment: Is not only a PRINT problem I am getting error 'Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '2016-01-05'.'

Comment: Are you able to provide the whole string? The part that you have provided is only 4000 characters long and in the question you mention 17178. I did look in the part provided and cannot see any issues.

Comment: The problem was when I was removing the last ' UNION ' with //
set @sql = left(@sql, len(@sql) - 7) - I changed the 7 to a 6 and it works ;-)

Comment: Great!! Did my solution help you with printing the string?

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if you are happy. If you need additional clarification, please let me know.