# OUTPUT is not displaying more than ch3794, col 3794, Ln 35,

Tags: sql-server

i want to get all the records of the table but it is not displaying more than  ch3794, col 3794, Ln 35

how to get the Query Output in HTML Format to send the report in Email?

```
    DECLARE @xmlthree NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @bodythree NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @xmlthree = CAST(( SELECT 
[SerName] AS 'td','',
[IPAddress] AS 'td','',
[SName] AS 'td','', 
[Status] AS 'td','',
[TTaken] AS 'td','',
[MName] AS 'td','',
[TTime] AS 'td'
FROM  [dbo].[Error-details]
ORDER BY TTaken DESC  
FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))


SET @bodythree ='<html><body><H3>Web Report</H3>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th> SerName </th> 
<th> IPAddress </th> 
<th> SName </th> 
<th> Status </th> 
<th> TTaken </th> 
<th> MName </th> 
<th> TTime </th> </tr>'    

SET @bodythree = @bodythree + @xmlthree +'</table></body></html>'
Print @bodythree
Go
```

i am getting the below output, some of the records are missing in the OUTPUT:-
[the red mark in the image at the end of the line in my problme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WA6Yu.png)

Comment: Please shorten your code & examples to only include the relevant part, instead of just dumping everything here, without even really asking anything

Comment: Included what i need.! my question is some of the records are missing in the HTML Table output. please let me know if you need any

Comment: You should include what **we** need. A proper question with a short example of your issue. We do not need dump of your whole code and HTML.

Comment: i did added the required fields with the screen shot. and shorten the code , is this enough for your need?

Comment: Did you ever calculate how many characters your output is? My guess is 4000.

Comment: yes, i just calculated the characters it is more than 15,000 characters, and also it depends on the records in different tables.

Comment: Maybe your problem is not understanding English good enough... I didn't ask how much data you have. I asked how about the **output** length.

Answer (score 0):

This is a probably just from the limitation of `print`, `print` is only returning the first 8 thousand characters for `varchar` and 4 thousand for `nvarchar`.

To print `nvarchar` strings shorter than 16,000 characters, you can use:

```
print cast(@bodythree as ntext);
```

For strings longer than that, you can use:

```
declare @String nvarchar(max)=@bodythree;
declare @CurrentEnd bigint, @offset int;
while len(@String) > 1
begin
  if charindex(char(10), @String) between 1 and 4000
  begin
    set @CurrentEnd =  charindex(char(10), @String) -1;
    set @offset = 2;
  end
  else
  begin
    set @CurrentEnd = 4000;
    set @offset = 1;
  end   
  print substring(@String, 1, @CurrentEnd);
  set @string = substring(@String, @CurrentEnd+@offset, len(@String));
end;
```

Combination of answers from here: [How to print VARCHAR(MAX) using Print Statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7850477/2333499)

---

For the second method to work with your situation, you need to add new lines to your body, like so:

```
declare @xmlthree nvarchar(max), @bodythree nvarchar(max);
set @xmlthree = replace(cast((
      select
          SerName as 'td',''
        , ipaddress as 'td',''
        , sname as 'td',''
        , [Status] as 'td',''
        , ttaken as 'td',''
        , mname as 'td',''
        , ttime as 'td'
      from  dbo.Error-details
      order by ttaken desc
      for xml path('tr'), elements ) as nvarchar(max))
    ,'</tr>','</tr>'+char(10))
set @bodythree ='<html><body><H3>Web Report</H3>
<table border="1">
<tr>
<th> SerName </th>
<th> ipaddress </th>
<th> sname </th>
<th> Status </th>
<th> ttaken </th>
<th> mname </th>
<th> ttime </th>
</tr>
'
set @bodythree = @bodythree + @xmlthree +'</table></body></html>';
declare @String nvarchar(max)=@bodythree;
declare @CurrentEnd bigint, @offset int;
while len(@String) > 1
begin
  if charindex(char(10), @String) between 1 and 4000
  begin
    set @CurrentEnd =  charindex(char(10), @String) -1;
    set @offset = 2;
  end
  else
  begin
    set @CurrentEnd = 4000;
    set @offset = 1;
  end
  print substring(@String, 1, @CurrentEnd);
  set @string = substring(@String, @CurrentEnd+@offset, len(@String));
end;
```

Comment: This works fine for me , but only thing is sometimes it breaks in HTML Tag so it displays some of the characters outside the table, i tried increasing  the charindex but no luck. is there any other way to get ride of this.

Comment: @karhtik When you "send the report in Email" it should not be truncated. It is only truncated when previewing with `print`.

Comment: @karhtik Updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring and assigning values to variables try a direct select statement. Something like this

```
SELECT
    '<html><body><H3>Web Report</H3>
    <table border="1">
    <tr>
    <th> SerName </th> 
    <th> IPAddress </th> 
    <th> SName </th> 
    <th> Status </th> 
    <th> TTaken </th> 
    <th> MName </th> 
    <th> TTime </th> </tr>'+ISNULL(
    CAST(( SELECT 
    [SerName] AS 'td','',
    [IPAddress] AS 'td','',
    [SName] AS 'td','', 
    [Status] AS 'td','',
    [TTaken] AS 'td','',
    [MName] AS 'td','',
    [TTime] AS 'td'
    FROM  [dbo].[Error-details]
    ORDER BY TTaken DESC  
    FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),'')
    +'</table></body></html>'
```