# Why VARCHAR(MAX) is not saving the entire value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a base 64 image with **78232** characters (didn't put the encode because of obvious reasons).

When I save to a VARCHAR(max) column in SQL Server, I'm not getting the entire value. I'm getting a string with only **43679** characters

Since I read that VARCHAR(max) can store up to `2^31-1 = 2.147.483.647` characters I think something is wrong.

Can someone explain why?

Comment: How are you checking the value?  I think this is an issue with SSMS.  If you just use `LENGTH()` you should see the full length.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, you're right! The length is correct, but how to retrieve all text then?

Comment: . . Here is one method:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850477/how-to-print-varcharmax-using-print-statement.  I've used something similar in the past.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you very much

Comment: You could also store the **binary image** into a `VARBINARY(MAX)` column, and avoid the time- and space-consuming "Base64" encoding ....

Comment: Right click on SSMS query window and select "Query Options..." option. On Query options popup there is setting under "Results >>Grid" tab for "Maximum Characters Retrieved".

Comment: `43679` is an *oddly specific* number. And in fact if you searched on `SQL Server 43679` you'd have found plenty of results.

Comment: Classic example of why choosing the correct datatype is so important.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever . . . I can empathize with the OP.  When I first encountered this, I assumed there was some error on my part and wasted a lot of error trying to find a bug.  I would never think that 43,679 is some magic number in software.  65,535 -- yes, but not 43,679.  Anyone know where it comes from?

Comment: @GordonLinoff According to [this](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7209) the limitation is in the results pane of SSMS query window and is mentioned as a known issue. I think "obscure" might be a better adjective if true.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, that's pretty obscure. But thank you very much for your explanation.