# SQL Server : how to print variable breaking each line and going above varchar(MAX)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following query:

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Script VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @fillfactor INT

DECLARE TableCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT '[' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME([object_id]) + '].[' + name + ']' AS TableName
    FROM sys.tables

OPEN TableCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'ALTER INDEX ALL ON ' + @TableName + ' REBUILD' + ')' 

    SELECT @Script = CAST(@Script + @sql AS VARCHAR(MAX))

    FETCH NEXT FROM TableCursor INTO @TableName
END

CLOSE TableCursor
DEALLOCATE TableCursor

PRINT @Script
GO
```

New to SQL Server. Right now it is limited to 8000 characters, I wanted to know how can I print `@Script` with all the tables and at the same time each line on `@sql` break into a new line.

Comment: Why don't you simply print on each loop iteration?

Comment: You right... Now onto the VARCHAR(MAX) one. Do you have any idea how can I go above 8k characters?

Comment: In SQL Server Management Studio, you cannot. No more than 8k will be printed or displayed in one go. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850477/how-to-print-varcharmax-using-print-statement for an alternative.

Comment: Your code already stores more than 8k characters. Check the length with `SELECT LEN( @Script)`

Comment: Remove the closing parenthesis and add a line feed and/or carriage return.

Comment: `VARCHAR(MAX)` can store up to **2 billion** characters (not just 8000) .....