# Cast FOR XML to Varchar(max)

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssms, for-xml

I have a query that returns XML which I want to convert to varchar. My query returns 93,643 characters of XML. When I try to cast my xml result as varchar, I only get 43,679 characters when I copy the result set to a text editor. When I do len(xmlString), I get 93,643 characters.

I know from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761124/how-many-characters-in-varcharmax) that varchar(max) can have up to 2^31 characters and 1 byte = 1 character, but it seems to be cutting off my data.

Do XML characters count as more than 1 byte? Why am I not able to select all the data from my xml result?

```
CAST((SELECT COLUMNS FROM TABLE FOR XML PATH('Name'), TYPE) AS VARCHAR(MAX)
```

Comment: It doesn't fix my issue. I already changed those.

Comment: You need to stop using Management Studio to return large strings (or "verify" their length).

Comment: I think that you should check this post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897950/how-do-you-view-all-text-from-an-ntext-or-nvarcharmax-in-ssms/11900246#11900246

Answer (score 0):

This is just a limitation of the Managementstudio.
With a testquery on a bigger table  I get described 43,679 characters.
The same Query deliveres 267089 characters in a application via ADO.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need to cast you xml data to varchar(max) but if you just want to copy all data don't cast it at all. In this case in the result window you will see one cell with a clickable value (just like a web link). Click it and all your data will be opened in a new window, then you will be able to save it like a file or just copy it. Hope it helps.

Comment: But even XML output is limited to 64K within SSMS. If you want to use SSMS to validate the length, just check DATALENGTH(). If you want to validate the whole string, use something else.