# Cast XML To nvarchar(max) Linq Entity Query

Tags: xml, entity-framework, casting, linq-to-entities

im use This Query T-SQL

> SELECT 
>       [Extent1].[ProductAttributeCombinationId] AS [ProductAttributeCombinationId], 
>       [Extent1].[ProductId] AS [ProductId], 
>       [Extent1].[ProductAttributeXML] AS [ProductAttributeXML], 
>       [Extent1].[StockQuantity] AS [StockQuantity], 
>       [Extent1].[Price] AS [Price]
>       FROM [dbo].[ProductAttributeCombination] AS [Extent1]
>       WHERE N'' = cast([Extent1].[ProductAttributeXML] as nvarchar(max))

Can this Query To LINQ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**Linqer**](http://www.sqltolinq.com/) for that.

> Linqer is a SQL to LINQ conversion tool. It helps learning LINQ and
>   convert existing SQL statements.
>
> Not every SQL statement can be converted to LINQ, but Linqer covers
>   many different types of SQL expressions. Linqer supports both .NET
>   languages - C# and Visual Basic.
>
> Because LINQ is a part of the C# and VB languages, it is sensitive to
>   data type conversion. Linqer performs required type castings in the
>   produced LINQ statements.

Comment: im use linqer the result query : from Extent1 in db.ProductAttributeCombinations
where
  "'" == SqlFunctions.StringConvert((Double)Extent1.ProductAttributeXML)
select new {
  ProductAttributeCombinationId = Extent1.ProductAttributeCombinationId,
  ProductId = Extent1.ProductId,
  ProductAttributeXML = Extent1.ProductAttributeXML,
  StockQuantity = Extent1.StockQuantity,
  Price = Extent1.Price
}

Comment: Not clear what is your issue here. Can you tell us ?

Comment: the result query in linqer not worked and error message is : " Error Compiling Expression: Error Compiling Expression: Delegate 'System.Func<Store.ProductAttributeCombination,int,bool>' does not take 1 arguments
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type
Cannot convert type 'string' to 'double' "

Comment: Did you test the `linqer` with simple example ? check whether is that installed and configured correctly.

Comment: Yes the sql query converted to linq with linqer but not worked There was another way

Comment: If it's not working for a simple query itself then you have not installed it correctly ?

Comment: im download trial version from site, Might be an issue be?

Comment: Trial versions are working correctly.Try to install it again after removing the current installation.

Comment: Worked in Linq To SQL but when To Select LINQ TO ENTITY Difrents Result View

Comment: the result for LINQ TO SQL : from Extent1 in db.ProductAttributeCombination
where
  "'" == Convert.ToString(Extent1.ProductAttributeXML)
select new {
  ProductAttributeCombinationId = Extent1.ProductAttributeCombinationId,
  ProductId = Extent1.ProductId,
  ProductAttributeXML = Extent1.ProductAttributeXML,
  StockQuantity = Extent1.StockQuantity,
  Price = Extent1.Price
} this worked

Comment: [Column(TypeName = "xml")]
[Required]
public string ProductAttributeXML { get; set; } 
The Model in Code First

Comment: this is propery of model in EF CodeFirst and Difference Result in Linqer when use linq to entity converted is : from Extent1 in db.ProductAttributeCombinations
where
  "'" == SqlFunctions.StringConvert((Double)Extent1.ProductAttributeXML)
select new {
  ProductAttributeCombinationId = Extent1.ProductAttributeCombinationId,
  ProductId = Extent1.ProductId,
  ProductAttributeXML = Extent1.ProductAttributeXML,
  StockQuantity = Extent1.StockQuantity,
  Price = Extent1.Price
}

Comment: The error Message : Error Compiling Expression: Error Compiling Expression: Delegate 'System.Func<B.ProductAttributeCombination,int,bool>' does not take 1 arguments
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type
Cannot convert type 'string' to 'double'
Delegate 'System.Func<B.ProductAttributeCombination,int,bool>' does not take 1 arguments
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type
Cannot convert type 'string' to 'double'

Comment: adjust those things manually. That tool does not support all data types.

Comment: Can Use EdmFunction cast xml to nvarchar(max)?

Comment: may be helped to you :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13958195/cast-for-xml-to-varcharmax