# Number of real character allowed in SQL Server Varchar(max) or Text data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I need to know the maximum number of characters I can put into a varchar(max) or text field using Sql Server. In [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx) page I have found that the maximum number of bytes for storage is 2GB (2^31 - 1). Since I suppose, according to this page and other I've searched, the Unicode character is 2 byte sized, I conclude that I have to divide the total byte size for the Unicode character size, which does not give an integer result. Any sugestions where I am failing? Why does the page say the maximum string length is 2^31 - 1 instead of 2^31?

Comment: I think you are confusing varchar(max) with nvarhar(max).  varchar(max) has one byte per character

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761124/how-many-characters-in-varcharmax Without going into detail it depends on character encoding being used. http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4270049/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-characters-that-nvarcharmax-will-hold

Comment: Yes, Rob, I am confusing. Varchar is NON-Unicode. I thought it was Unicode. And xQbert, the first link was very useful. Thanks. The answer, by the way, is 2^31-3 characters (for varchar).

Answer (score 0):

From SQL Server 2012 Help:

Variable-length, non-Unicode string data. ndefines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 
8,000. maxindicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB). The storage size is the actual 
length of the data entered + 2 bytes. The ISO synonyms for varcharare char varyingor character
varying.