# SQL Server - updating Varchar(max) column using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have table containing column `Email` which is `varchar(MAX)` and I am trying to update it using stored procedure. When the string length is greater than 8000 characters, I get this error

> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been
>   terminated.

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SaveData]
    @Id BIGINT,
    @Email varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE tb_data
    SET Email = @Email
    WHERE Id = @Id  
END
```

Please note that datatype for email is set to `varchar(MAX)`

Interesting thing is when I try to run the update query manually, it works!

I've done this several times but cannot figure out why it's not working in this case.

Comment: if the column in table is varchar(MAX), why stored proc parameter is nvarchar(max)?

Comment: I was wondering why the email address is greater than 8000 characters ? , this link can help you http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic647815-145-1.aspx

Comment: use the sql profile to find the actual data passing from your app.

Comment: @Harsh: fixed. It is varchar only.

Comment: @JapzDivino: This is column will save the email templates not email id.

Comment: @Sangram , ah i see.. hope all links below can help you :)

Comment: @Chandru: i've added print statement to check what data is being passed and the data is truncated after 8000th character but it is possible that actual data could be more than what print shows. I think i better use profiler

Comment: @Sangram try changing it as nvarchar(max) in column and also in store proc

Comment: Is this the complete stored proc? Are you sure you are not assigning value of @email parameter somewhere within the stored proc to some varchar variable and in the process truncating beyond 8000 characters?

Answer (score -1):

Hope this can help you:

[Microsoft MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx)

[Maximum Capacity Specifications for SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)

1 byte = 1 character >> 2^31-1 characters

**varchar [ ( n | max ) ]**

> Variable-length, non-Unicode string data. n defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 8,000. max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB). The storage size is the actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes. The ISO synonyms for varchar are char varying or character varying.

[How many characters in varchar(max)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761124/how-many-characters-in-varcharmax)

[Maximum size of a varchar(max) variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611394/maximum-size-of-a-varcharmax-variable)

Comment: -1: From the question,it seems like OP does understand what he is doing and need help for particular scenario. Posting links to MSDN articles will not help in such cases.

Comment: @user2564977 I respect your opinion , i'm just trying to help :) Regards