# Auto generate a Varchar Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to auto-generate a variable of data type `VARCHAR` without a certain limit which means It has to be like `'AB1'`, `'AB2'`, `'AB3'` ... up to infinity

Here there are mainly two points:

1. There is no identity column in this table
2. And sometimes it may have another pattern data in this column like `'AB1','AB2','AB3','PK1','AB4' Which is (AB(3+1))`

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893988/how-to-make-mysql-table-primary-key-auto-increment-with-some-prefix

Comment: You want this to happen in a create table statement or you want it in a select query?

Comment: The pattern will be similar or can we expect records like 'ABC123'?

Comment: So infinity would be a problem.  A `varchar(max)` field in SQL Server can hold 2^31-3 characters - hardly enough to support infinity!

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761124/how-many-characters-in-varcharmax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wish it can helpful for you.

```
CREATE TABLE #tt(s VARCHAR(100),col1 INT )
INSERT INTO #tt
VALUES('AB1',1),('AB2',100),('AB3',2),('PK1',5),('AB4',20)
GO

DECLARE @prefix VARCHAR(100)='PK'
INSERT INTO #tt(s,col1)
SELECT @prefix+LTRIM(ISNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(v.num)=1 THEN CONVERT(INT,v.num) ELSE 0 END),0)+1),20
FROM #tt 
CROSS APPLY(VALUES(SUBSTRING(s,LEN(@prefix)+1,LEN(s)))) v(num)
WHERE LEFT(s,LEN(@prefix))=@prefix
GO 10

SELECT * FROM #tt
```

```
s
-----
AB1
AB2
AB3
PK1
AB4
PK2
PK3
PK4
PK5
PK6
PK7
PK8
PK9
PK10
PK11
PK12
PK13
PK14
PK15
PK16
PK17
PK18
PK19
PK20
PK21
```

Comment: After 'Pk10' It is getting 'Pk10' again and again @Nolan Shang

Comment: That error is because the MAX tread the values is string but number, so the 9 will greater then 10, so need convert the value to integer before get max